# Move last words of strings from one file to another

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file that contains:

/usr/bin/alias, /usr/bin/clear, /usr/bin/echo, /usr/bin/cat, /usr/bin/netstat,
/usr/sbin/shutdown, /usr/bin/less

and I need to move the last words to another file

```
alias
clear
echo
cat
netstat
shutdown
less
```

I have tried awk, grep, sed, cut all kinds of combinations but can't seem to get the right result

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Something like `sed 's|/usr/bin/||g; s|/usr/sbin/||g' file`?

Comment: Are the commands on individual lines or on one single, comma separated, line?

Comment: @jared_mamrot or simplier: `sed 's1/[^ ]*/11g'`

Comment: @jprice: So in the file, the strings are all in one line, and separated by a comma and a space? Or could the file contain more than one line? Your question is a bit unclear in this respect.

Comment: `sed -e 's@^.*/@@'` or `awk -F/ '{print $(NF)}'` or `grep -oE '[^/]+$'` however `cut` is probably not able to do this if the number of path components is variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:

`grep -Po '(?<=/)[^/]+$' filename`

-P means to use Perl style regex

-o means to output just the matched text

(?<=/) is a zero-width lookbehind to match the leading slash

[^/]+$ matches any text except a slash to the end of the line

Comment: This works if each file is its own line. Replace the `$` with `,` if they are comma-separated.

Comment: How is this any better than `awk -F/ '{print $NF}'`? Am I missing something?